# Console pauses after getting integer

Tags: c++, console-application

So when I created a program that takes 2 integers, add them together and write it to the console. The thing is that I'm learning to use multiple classes. The program works but after getting the first integer, the console pauses and only continues after I enter another integer. Can you guys hint/explain me what is going wrong?

```
int readNumber()
{
    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}

void writeAnswer(int result)
{
    cout << "The result is: " << result;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    readNumber();
    cin >> x;

    int y;
    readNumber();
    cin >> y;

    int result = x + y;

    writeAnswer(result);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `int x = readNumber();`
`int y = readNumber();`

Comment: You call `cin` from `readNumber` and you call `cin` again after function call. Remove call to `cin`s in `main()`.

Comment: You don't need `cin >>x` and `cin>>y`, that's what `readNumber()` function does it for you.

Comment: Ah, get it now. Thanks!

Comment: The whole main function could become: `writeAnswer(readNumber() + readNumber());`! So it seems you understand the usefulness of functions.

Comment: Thank you for the tip Arnav! Will definitely remember that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within this block of statements:

```
int x;
readNumber(); // first time
cin >> x; // second time
```

the `std::cin` object is called twice. That's why you are seeing the *pause*. Eliminate needless calls to `std::cin` and replace the above with:

```
int x = readNumber();
```

Do the same for the `y` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation. Not gonna make this mistake a second time now!

Comment: Also, please have a look at this [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) list.

Comment: Thanks. I was just looking for some books on C++. Any specific you recommend from that list? I do have programming experience so a barebones beginner book isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: @IvovanderBruggen Only at market rates. Kidding. That part is up to you.